# Extract and concatenate the same field from multiple records in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to be able to extract one field from multiple records from within a single table.  For example, assuming I have a schema as follows

userId, eventTimestamp, theField

And what I want to do is be able to concatenate all instances of the field 'theField' together into a single string for a given userId ordered by eventTimestamp.  And for an extra wrinkle, lets say I only want to include the first fiftiest oldest records.

My first attempt was to try something like:

```
 SELECT
 userId,
 eventTimestamp,
 LEAD(theField,0) OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY eventTimestamp) AS step0,
 LEAD(theField,1) OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY eventTimestamp) AS step1,
 ....,
 LEAD(theField,50) OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY eventTimestamp) AS step50,
```

And then the next step was to wrap that first step up in another SELECT statement as follows:

```
 SELECT userId, eventTimestamp, CONCAT(STRING(step0), STRING(step1),...,STRING(step50)) as concatenatedString
 FROM [whateverDataset.whateverTable],
 GROUP BY
 userId, eventTimestamp
```

This approach doesn't work though because if I have more than 50 steps (which I do), then I end up getting multiple rows for each of those outer SELECT statements, basically N-50 rows, where N = the total number of records for a particular userId. A 'solution' to this would be to have a HAVING statement in the inner SELECT statement to limit itself to only reporting the first 50 records, but overall this seems like a rather cumbersome solution.  In non-BigQuery variants of SQL the GROUP_CONCAT seems to be a good way to go forward, but it either doesn't work here or I lack the creativity to get it to work.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For BigQuery Legacy SQL:

```
SELECT
  userid, GROUP_CONCAT(theField) AS Fields
FROM (
  SELECT 
    userid, eventTimestamp, theField, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY eventTimestamp DESC) AS pos
  FROM YourTable
  ORDER BY eventTimestamp
)
WHERE pos < 51
GROUP BY userid
```

Please note: *inner ORDER BY does not guarantee the order of theField in GROUP_CONCAT. But, so far, in all practical cases I see the order is carrying. So, test carefuly*

> For BigQuery Standard SQL:
>   *Don't forget to uncheck `Use Legacy SQL` checkbox under <kbd>Show Options</kbd>*

```
SELECT 
  userid, 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(fields) FROM t.fields) AS fields
FROM (
  SELECT 
    userid, 
    ARRAY(SELECT theField FROM t.fields ORDER BY eventTimestamp) fields 
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      userid, 
      ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(theField, eventTimestamp)) fields
    FROM (
      SELECT
        userid,
        eventTimestamp,
        theField,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY eventTimestamp DESC) AS pos
      FROM YourTable
    ) 
    WHERE pos < 51
    GROUP BY userid
  ) t
) t
```

Comment: does STRING_AGG carries order?

Comment: @foxwendy - yes, string_agg even support order by and limit inside it  - see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#using-order-by-with-aggregate-functions for more - if you have more / specific questions - please post new question . Meantime if this answer somehow helped you - please consider voting it up :o)

Comment: @foxwendy - if you still have question - post new one and I (or someone else on SO) will try to answer it